Use Case configuration does not exist for Tax Type: , and Case ID : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} how to resolbe this error
i have field in purchase invoice which name is TDS section code when we click on it its gives me error like this
Use Case configuration does not exist for Tax Type: , and Case ID : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}]
i have expected that its not gives me any error while selection on TDS Selection

Is this problem really related to jQuery?
